# Connect Kibana container with Elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I've a VM which contains Docker and Elasticsearch (OS: Centos7). I would like to create a Kibana docker and connect with my ES.

The ES contains indices, if I type **curl -s http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices** I got the list of indices.

I used Dockerfile to create my Kibana image:

> docker build -t="kibana_test" .
>
> docker run --name kibana -e
>   ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://@IP:9200 -e
>   XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED=false -p 5600:5601 -d kibana_test

Well, if I put the address IP of my machine, I got this :

> plugin:elasticsearch@6.2.4     Request Timeout after 3000ms

[image]

And in my Docker logs I got thi message:

> License information from the X-Pack plugin could not be obtained from
>   Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster

How can I resolve this problem ?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: I see `http://@IP:9200` which IP ?

Comment: Sorry! @IP=10.10.10.99 IP address of my VM.

Comment: can you `curl -s http://10.10.10.99:9200/_cat/indices`

Comment: Nothing to display! I think curl -s http://10.10.10.99:9200/_cat/indices don't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, configure in `elasticsearch.yml` file.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
```

Then restart elasticsearh service first,

When build kibana container :

use this:

```
 -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://172.17.0.1:9200
```

check again.

Comment: Changing `elasticsearch.yml` and trying `curl -s http://10.10.10.99:9200/_cat/indices` doesn't work. It's displaying to me **Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.**

Comment: **transport.tcp.port: 9300** why ?

Comment: I got this : **plugin:elasticsearch@6.2.4  Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://172.17.0.1:9200**

Comment: change to `10.10.10.99:9200` , and try again.

Comment: did you curl curl -s http://10.10.10.99:9200/_cat/indices successfully  ?